# cannot download TeeChart Pro VCL

Tags: vcl, teechart

I used TeeChart Pro VCL With Source Code 2015.
My programming language is Embarcadero C++Builder XE7.
I use Windows 7 64bit.

When I downloaded TeeChart Pro VCL, TeeChart Pro VCL compile error
win 32 compile unsuccess, there is no：`Teexx.bpl、TeeDBxx.bpl、TeeUIxx.bpl、TeeGLxx.bpl、TeeQRxx.bpl、TeeProxx.bpl、TeeImagexx.bpl、TeeLanguagexx.bpl、TeeWorldxx.bpl`.

Please help to download TeeChart Pro VCL. Or do you have the introduction for set up?

Thank you.

*Log file shows*

```
VCLTee.TeeConst.pas(624)Error: E2066 Missing operator or semicolon. 
VCLTee.TeeConst.pas(624)Error: E2066 Missing operator or semicolon. 
VCLTee.TeeConst.pas(624)Error: E2052 Unterminated string 
VCLTee.TeeConst.pas(1042)Error: E2052 Unterminated string 
VCLTee.TeeConst.pas(624)Fatal: E2280 Unterminated conditional directive

Exception: Compilation aborted.
```

Comment: Might the file ending .pas suggest, that you try to compile pascal with a c++ compiler?

Answer (score 2):

You should use *TeeRecompile.exe* tool, supplied with the source code installation, to compile the sources and generate packages and some files for each specific environment.

Comment: @Linda it may be that VCLTee.TeeConst.pas is corrupted or TeeRecompile failed to restore it to its original state. Please try doing what Yeray Alonso suggested here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15522&p=68816&hilit=teeconst&sid=1ac6a3691fc3a8c5fc948e486c32fb05#p68816

Comment: the problem is similar, i tried the suggestion, but still no use. the problem is still the same.

Comment: and I update to XE8, then install TeeChart Pro VCL, still same.

Comment: even though I download the older version of 2014/09/24 and 215/01/23.
still no use.

Comment: @Linda, we have found some problems with Chinese operating systems? We are investigating. Can you confirm you are using that? Did you post something similar at our forums (http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15522#p69436)? In the meantime, being a source code customer, you have access to a binary installer, you could use that.

Comment: http://www.linksoft.com.tw/Data/TeeChartVCL.jpg
@ Narcis, please see the pic and help to solve

Comment: @Linda we found a problem with Chinese versions of Windows. Can you please confirm you are using a Chinese OS? Also, we suggested using binary installers for now. More info about this at this forums thread: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=69489&#p69482

Answer (score 1):

We have realized if you change the language for non-Unicode programs from Chinese to English, just for the time to compile the source code, you can compile the source code without problems.

We would like suggest you use the recommendation as workaround at the moment. To access to Languages for non-Unicode programs, you should only go to: **Panel Control->Region and Language->Administrative.**

Could you confirm if the workaround works for you?